# Responsively vertical aligning an element in one column with an element in another

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I frequently find myself with a two column layout, in which one column contains all the content and the other contains various extra elements. These need to be somewhat anchored to specific paragraphs in the first column to make any sense. An [example](http://extras.thetimes.co.uk/public/2013/mandela/):

[image: "Life of Mandela", via The Times]

While it appears to be three continuous columns, it's actually four separate rows, each with three columns -- that is, the first row contains the gallery block, the first paragraph and the "1918" timeline block; the second contains an offset region, the second paragraph and the illustration above the "1925" block, et cetera.

The upsides of this approach are that the extra content pieces (hereafter "blocks") are vertically aligned to the paragraph referencing them and are responsive due to being sized proportionate to the column width. The downsides are that it's not at all semantic, and having blocks taller than the main paragraph will stretch the height of the column and add blank space beneath it (Unless absolutely positioned, which these are).

I could [also make it a single 3-column row](http://codepen.io/aendrew/pen/Ihain), with the blocks added to the main content column above the referencing paragraph, and then absolute positioned into the blank space created by the outer columns. This is good in that it's much more semantic, but bad in that block widths won't reflect the column width defined by Bootstrap's grid, and thus are much more difficult to make responsive.

I could do the same but [put all the blocks one after another in each column](http://codepen.io/aendrew/pen/sDLCr), positioned vertically with bottom margins (or positioned relatively), but this is even more difficult to make responsive given the distance between blocks will change in a responsive layout when the central column is narrowed or widened. I could scale the text at different breakpoints to prevent the paragraph shape from changing, but that would probably reduce readability because I'd need to scale down on smaller devices.

Is there anything I'm missing? Put another way, **is there a clean, semantic way of vertically positioning an element in reference to another element?**

Comment: Also, if this is a better question for StackOverflow, please move it there. Thanks!

Comment: The only way you can position an element in relation to another element is if one is a child of the other. I'd personally opt to make each section it's own row with three columns

Answer (score 0):

Could this plugin answer your problems?

http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/

Comment: Hi Shannon, thanks for the response! Alas, I'm not sure that will do what I'm wanting it to -- I'm not wanting the elements to be fixed position, I want them to be static, i.e., to scroll with the page. I also get the feeling I'd experience the same issues as with the second example listed -- the blocks wouldn't be responsive.